# Swift SpriteKit add physics to user-drawn line

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I want to create a game in which the player draws a line with physics, similar to the game Happy Glass.

**What I have tried:**

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        touchPosition = location
    }
}

func draw(pos: CGPoint){
    let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
    node.position = CGPoint(x: pos.x, y: pos.y)
    node.size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: node.frame.width / 2)
    //set up the physics

    self.addChild(node)
}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    if touching{
        draw(pos: touchPosition)
    }

}
```

So I basically change the touchPosition variable every time a touch is moved(when the user drags their finger across the screen) then I have didSimulatePhysics as repeating timer to add small circles at the touchPosition with physics on them.

**The Problem:**

This all works. The only problem is that they are too spread out. I want it to be a continuous line but the touchesMoved method is not recognizing enough touches so it looks like this.

[image]

Is there a way to recognize touches more frequently so I can fill an entire line or some way to possibly do this with a CGPath? I just can't have these gaps in between these points basically because I can't have other nodes with physicBodies falling between the cracks.

The other thing is that the points are constantly moving off the screen with a SKAction, so I can just draw a CGPath line from the current touch to the last touch because the point from the last touch will have moved slightly so i'm kind of confused in what to do and any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Your issue isnt more touches, your issue is you do not interpolate the line between touches.  UITouch has a previous location, use that with your current location to create a line.  If you need an arc, then you are going to have to figure that out based on previously known data